# What are possible solutions in using Offline First Sync with MongoDB and alternative to PouchDB/CouchDB?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I would like to ask if you have alternatives into using Pouch/Couch db into developing offline first apps that syncs automatically with MongoDb. My current issue is that Pouch/Couch seems to have the trend going down and looking forward to the future seems like it will die soon. Clients are on and off the internet so I need to create an offline first app that syncs later on when connection is established.

Comment: This is for ReactJS by the way.

Comment: Why do you think CouchDB / PouchDB will "die soon"?

Comment: Asking for software recommendations isn't [on-topic for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). However, there is a sibling [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) site that focuses on those.